# SQL Server - window function to generate a parittion id?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I want a query that will generate an id number for each grouping

if I have a table like

```
+------+------+
| Col1 | Col2 |
+------+------+
|    1 | a    |
|    1 | a    |
|    1 | a    |
|    2 | b    |
|    2 | b    |
|    3 | c    |
+------+------+
```

how can I generate the number inside col1 - so that each value of 'a' will always have the same id generated.

I would imagine it looks something like:

```
select What_is_this_Called() over (partition by col2 order by col2) as col1 
    ,col2
from myTable
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [DENSE_RANK()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms173825.aspx)

> Returns the rank of rows within the partition of a result set, without any gaps in the ranking. The rank of a row is one plus the number of distinct ranks that come before the row in question.

**Sample:**

```
SELECT DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col2) AS col1, col2 
FROM myTable
```